# Xamarin Android using Dependency Injection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Im currently working on a DDD layer architecture. I am not sure how to use Dependency Injection on Android project solution. Currently my Android solution holds a reference to class library solution. I have used Unity on my service layer and register container via WebApiConfig.cs. 
My question is, how do i go about using Unity on Android side in order to run on start up, would be grateful if code was included. I dont want to new-up the container through main activity of Android. I want the container to register behind the process i.e. AppStart or Global asax where it does it for you for MVC apps. Is there a way to do it for Android? 
Also I noticed on Main Activity I am unable to create constructor. I guess this isnt possible but how do I go about holding object reference to my Class Library solution ? example that i attempted to do:

```
private IExample _ex;

MainActivity(IExample ex){
_ex = ex; //depedency Injection rather than newing it up 
}

public void DoSomething(){
 _ex.HelloWorld(); 
}
```

Also for each of my layer do I need to install and create container in order to resolve current solution dependency ? or can I use container from android which would resolve all dependency in each layer as DDD goes from outer to inner ?

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but for future readers:

Subclassing the application class would do what you are after in regard to registering the container at start up.

```cs
[Application]
public class App : Application
{
    public static UnityContainer Container { get; set; }

    public App( IntPtr javaRef, JniHandleOwnership transfer ) : base( javaRef, transfer )
    {

    }

    public override void OnCreate( )
    {
        base.OnCreate( );

        Container = new UnityContainer( );

        Container.RegisterType<ISomeService, ServiceImplementation>( );
    }
}
```

Application Class:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.Application/

That's all I can offer at this stage... I'm still in the process of implementing a full Xam.Android solution with Unity & new to dependency injection in general.